# Issue with output class

Tags: content

So i'm trying to output the content of a template in xml and saw that the documentation mentioned an output class with functions like set_content_type (https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/libraries/output.html). When I try to call this function using:

> ee()->output->set_content_type('xml');

the page loads with an error:

> "Call to undefined method EE_Output::set_content_type()"

Other functions of the output class such as "parse_exec_vars" work fine. Am I forgetting something that allows this function to be used? Also I am currently using expressionengine4

Comment: I'm trying to directly output a PDF file in a secure manner and experiencing this same issue...still trying to figure out why I get the error "Call to undefined method EE_Output::set_content_type()" when trying to set the mime type for display. I can output the file content, but without setting the content type, it just shows the raw information in the browser window.

Comment: @Te3d this is an old question. You'll have better luck getting an answer if you post a new question with specific details about your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not relevant but in the Add-ons there's XML encode. Is it installed?

Comment: I’ll have to check when I go back into work. That’s a good idea though!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I made sure that add on was installed but I wasn’t able to figure out why I couldn’t use set_content_type. I ended up realizing EE let’s you process php on input even with xml file types. Thanks for trying to help though!